# What Ansible version does AWX 19.1.0 offer?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am using AWX 17.1.0 which offers Ansible version 2.9.18. The older Ansible version is becoming a bit of an issue. There does not seem to be a documented way to upgrade Ansible in an existing Ansible installation. I am using btw a local docker setup.

Is this correct? That there is no documented / approved way to update Ansible?

Local docker I think is no longer an option so there is also no way to upgrade my AWX to 19.1.0.

On the website I cannot find any information on the Ansible version of AWX 19.1.0. What is Ansible version of AWX 19.1.0?

Comment: You would basically need to use a custom virtualenv with AWX with a different version of Ansible installed if you want to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct? That there is no documented / approved way to update Ansible?

Yes. Meanwhile I have done it by building my own custom image and it worked at the time (at least for our team usage). But it is clearly not recommended. (Note that the way the images are built has drastically changed since I have done this)

> Local docker I think is no longer an option so there is also no way to upgrade my AWX to 19.1.0.

I made the same interpretation mistake as you and that is actually a wrong statement. This install type just doesn't have the same visibility in the current documentation (a simple link on the install page) and has been moved to a [separate page](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/tools/docker-compose/README.md)

> I cannot find any information on the Ansible version of AWX 19.1.0

I didn't either briefly looking at the code, but the easiest way is probably to spawn a test install and try.

Answer (score 1):

```
sh-4.4$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.11.0rc2]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/runner/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/runner/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.3 (default, Aug 31 2020, 16:03:14) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
  jinja version = 2.10.3
  libyaml = True
```